# How to find out bug list for particular versions?

Tags: error, versions, documentation

Hi I have installed blender 2.81 and it has issues that are different to 2.8.

How can I find out what bugs are for my version rather than all versions like bug tracker etc?

Geodesic domes crashes my computer, rock generator is not working, and sometimes (not often) materials have to be deleted as they stay pink even with changes.

Probably lots more I don't know of.  Also push pull is still not updated, though that was on blender today yesterday so it's known.

Also bool tool tab does not work but fast carve does (which is nice), my preferred.

But how can I know if 2.82 is better or worse without having to figure it out myself, or 2.83?  They all have different issues.

Comment: If geodesic dome crashes your entire computer and you're having issue with pink material in cases where all texture files are present, this sound more like an issue with your computer than with Blender, e.g. a graphics driver not working properly. That being said, there's a lot of work happening in Blender's development and only the bug trackers and Blender's git repository contain all the information about open and fixed bugs. You will have to ask a specific question to get a specific answer.

Comment: In order to find all bug reports for a specific version you will have to create a query that includes the version string you're interested in. For example [this query](https://developer.blender.org/maniphest/query/8UnBrQkYTXVt/#R) would be for any bug report containing "2.82" from the *BF Blender* project that has been resolved. [This one](https://developer.blender.org/maniphest/query/bVYGgyraiTj5/#R) is for all the bug reports that contain "2.82" that are confirmed (and open).

Comment: In general the newer version is better since it includes bug fixes for previous issues and new feature. Whether potentially new bugs are problematic for you is something that we can't answer.